# How to optimize room database query called in loop to improve performance

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'm developing and Android Application using a Room database with a single table called 'Operations'.

Each operation has a Year, a Category and a TotalAmmount.

I'm triying to get the sum of each Category in a year. I'm doing this:

```
totalsAndCategories= new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < Categories.length; i++)
{
    totalsAndCategories.put(Categories[i], getTotalOfCategoryInYear(Categories[i], 2018));
}

return categoriesAndQuantitiesIngresos;
```

And my query is this:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as total FROM OperacionesTable WHERE FechaYear = :year AND Categoria = :category ORDER BY FechaYear DESC")
float getTotalOfCategoryInYear(String category, int year);
```

This work fine but I'm wondering if I could somehow reduce the number of queries to speed up my application as the UI first loads empty and then it populates with the data retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can improve

1) your query is called in loop based on category and year parameter, you take category and/or both out of loop, execute same query before loop but with year and/or category as group by clause. So you will have relevant data already in place, just put it in correct  text fields.

2) You should not run and update UI using android main thread, but consider to use other threads for this task. AsyncTask is very easy to implement, it can perform database stuff in background, and update UI with results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `group by`:

```
SELECT FechaYear, Categoria, SUM(Cantidad) as total
FROM OperacionesTable
WHERE FechaYear = :year 
GROUP BY FechaYear, Categoria;
```

Don't use loops and cursors when you can express what you want as a single query.